# having clause is not working in sql

Tags: sql, rdbms

I dont understand whats wrong in this statment.

```
  Select customername,LEN(address) 
  FROM customers group by customername having LEN(address) = 13;
```

This is the error message
**HAVING clause (LEN(address)=13) without grouping or aggregation.**

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your query isn't sensible.

Comment: Why the group by? If all you need is the customers having an address of 13 characters, a simple `WHERE` clause would suffice.

Comment: If **SELECT COUNT(CustomerID), Country
FROM Customers
GROUP BY Country
HAVING COUNT(CustomerID) > 5;** works than why that one is not working

Comment: @NEKIBURRAHMAN I already told you why. `COUNT` is an aggregation function, `LEN` is not. Please read about SQL and how it works

Comment: Thanks. I got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither `address` nor `LEN(address)` is in the `GROUP BY`.  So, you either need to add them or wrap the expressions in an aggregation function:

```
SELECT customername, MAX(LEN(address))
FROM customers 
GROUP BY customername 
HAVING MAX(LEN(address)) = 13;
```

Or if you just want customers with a length of 13, perhaps no aggregation is needed at all:

```
SELECT customername
FROM customers 
WHERE LEN(address) = 13;
```

Comment: If you just want customers where the address length is 13, then the second query is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with the where clause

```
  Select customername,LEN(address) as lenadressnamecolumn
  FROM customers where LEN(address) = 13;
```

Comment: The above one works with count function. Why it is not working with len function

Comment: @NEKIBURRAHMAN because `LEN` isn't an aggregation function, it's a scalar one

Comment: @Lamak yes I did it fast and make a mistake, I updated the answer

Comment: @NEKIBURRAHMAN Yes indeed, I was thinking I using a where clause and I made a mistake in the middle, I correct the query

Comment: @damian Lattenero please edit you answer. It wont work

Comment: @NEKIBURRAHMAN Oh yes yes, sorry, that's it! I hope I could help!

Comment: @NEKIBURRAHMAN That's was my original idea from the begining, next time I will try it 20 times before post it...